# Custom positioning of ListFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have an `Activity` that loads a `FrameLayout`containing a `SearchView` and `Button` when created.  The button's `onClick` method loads a custom `ListFragment` on top of the main `FrameLayout`.

I override the `onCreate` method of the `ListFragment` to load my custom `ArrayAdapter`and populate the list with values from a string array that I manually create for now.  All of this works properly but I would like to load the `ListFragment` at the bottom of the screen.

I have tried changing the gravity of the main `FrameLayout` to bottom, since it is the parent of the `ListFragment` but this makes the `SearchView` and `Button` drop to the bottom of the screen along with the `ListFragment`.

In this example, I am loading three rows in the list.  How can I move the `ListFragment` down so that only the first row is visible at the bottom of the screen with the other two rows below it (off the screen)?

My MapActivity is the main `Activity`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MapActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        }
    }

    // Define the onShowTimesButtonClick listener
    public void onShowTimesButtonClick(View view){

        // Instantiate timeListFragment
        TimeListFragment timeListFragment = new TimeListFragment();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, timeListFragment, "timeList");
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

The layout of the MapActivity

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchBar"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="#656565"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timesButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:text="@string/times_button"
        android:onClick="onShowTimesButtonClick"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

TimeListFragment is my custom `ListFragment`.

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TimeListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public TimeListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Temporary time data
        String[] times = new String[]{"1:00", "0:30", "0:45"};

        // Load the time data
        setListAdapter(new TimesListArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_times_list_row, R.id.listText, times));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_times_list, container, false);

        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

        container.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return view;
    }
}
```

The layout for TimeListFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ListView android:id= "@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="No data"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have so far. I can move the `ListFragment` to the bottom of the screen by setting the gravity to bottom.  In the `onCreateView` method of the TimeListFragment, I was applying the `layoutParams` to the container; according to the Android documentation, this container is the parent view that the fragment's UI is attached to.  In order to apply the `layoutParams` to the fragment itself, I had to find the fragment view first by calling the `findViewById` on the inflated view.

The correct code for the `onCreateView` is shown below

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_times_list, container, false);

        View fragmentView = view.findViewById(R.id.timesList);

        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

        fragmentView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return view;
    }
```